# jquery accordian question

Tags: jquery

I'm breaking my back over this http://rankingclimber.com/test_jquery/index2.php

I put the jquery css, js folders in the directory test_jquery where index2.php is

and i used the following code on this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

However it's not appearing like it should on the above link.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a problem with the jquery ui file.  If you use Firebug to expand the script tag on your test page above, it reads "The requested URL /test_jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to call the jQuery script inside the  tags.  Additionally, it looks like your script links to jQuery don't actually go anywhere - you need to upload jQuery to your server so that the URL specified in the  tags points in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is this css path css/themename/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css ok? Are you sure?

For a test purpose only, try to put them all in the same directory.

Comment: Why don't you put your jquery code inside <head></head>? It's kind of pattern.